# How to make nested for loops not increase frequency of actions within the for loop

Tags: java, loops

I am currently using nested for loops to see if two rectangles have intersected or not.

```
for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < enemies.size(); j++) {
        if(!enemies.get(i).pureHitbox.intersects(enemies.get(j).pureHitbox) && i != j) {
            enemies.get(i).action();
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, the action the objects do increase in frequency by the amount of objects in the ArrayList. The current action is to move 3 in any direction, but if there are 2 in the ArrayList, it will move 6, if there are 3, it will move 9, etc.

I can't think of any way to make this work effectively.

Comment: What do the `intersects` and `action` methods do?

Comment: `intersects()` is a method from `java.awt.Rectangle`, `action()`, like I said, moves the rectangle 3 in any direction @SBylemans

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is when you search intersection and e.g. A and B have intersection, you make an action twice (*A intersects B* and *B intersects A*). All you need, is just check whether given action was executed for given A and B or not.

```
for(int i = 0, total = enemies.size(); i < total - 1; i++)
    for(int j = i + 1; j < total; j++)
        if(!enemies.get(i).pureHitbox.intersects(enemies.get(j).pureHitbox))
            enemies.get(i).action();
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out. It was very simple, all I had to do was add a break after it moved once.